# copying entire directory from one location to another using groovy scripting

Tags: groovy

i saw its simple enough to copy a file using groovy like

```
new File('c:/temp/dst.zip') << new File('c:/temp/src.zip').bytes
```

is there a simpler way to copy the entire directory structure? 
I am trying to avoid recursively iterating and creating the whole structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is with AntBuilder

```
new AntBuilder().copy( todir:'/path/to/destination/folder' ) {
  fileset( dir:'/path/to/src/folder' )
}
```